# JNI_CreateJavaVM call is suspending execution

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am in OSX 10.11. I am developing an application using `C and Java`. I have installed Oracle `Java8` on Mac. I am coding using Xcode.

I am trying to create `java virtual machine environment` within the application. I am trying to do so with JNI function `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. As I am using Java1.8.0_92, I am using `libjvm.dylib` as the library where to look for `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. I have included `libjvm.dylib` in Framework folder of Xcode. I have also provided @rpath and library path.

The problem is, the application is getting built successfully however, whenever I am trying to execute it, once the execution is reaching to `JNI_CreateJavaVM` function, the execution is getting suspended within `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, and `Xcode` is loading its debug environment and showing the following in Thread display window.

```
0x1040172b4: movl   (%rsi), %eax
0x1040172b6: leaq   0xf8(%rbp), %rsi
0x1040172bd: vmovdqu %ymm0, (%rsi)
0x1040172c1: vmovdqu %ymm7, 0x20(%rsi)
0x1040172c6: vmovdqu %ymm8, 0x40(%rsi)
0x1040172cb: vmovdqu %ymm15, 0x60(%rsi)
```

I am not able to understand what went wrong? Can you please help?

Code for calling JNI_CreateJavaVM is as follows:
————————————————————————

```
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib:”;
options[1].optionString = "-Xms1024m";
options[2].optionString = "-Xmx2048m";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.8
vm_args.nOptions = noOptions;
vm_args.options = 3;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

Comment: Your CLASSPATH doesn't look right. Why are you specifying the JVM there?

Comment: Even if I remove that, there is no change in situation. My application is compiling fine, but the issue is coming during runtime.

Comment: `vm_args.options = 3` can't be right. Should be `vm_args.nOptions = 3; vm_args.options = options;`

Comment: JNI_CreateJavaVM() intentionally raises (and catches) access violation exception. I left a detailed answer with workarounds, but it was deleted(!) by an overzealous moderator.